# requirejs module containing modules

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a library which internally uses AMD modules (requirejs). I want to return some methods from those modules as a public API. At the moment i'm using a sychronous require call to do this.

eg:

```
// library
define("a", function(){
    define("b", ['somedep','anotherdep'], function(dep, dep2){
        return { something: "x"};
    });

    return {
        b: require('b').something
    };
});



// then to use it.
require(['a'], function(a){
});
```

However this gives the error.
Error: Module name "b" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])

I don't want to expose the internal define calls externally (by flattening out all the defines) since i don't want library consumers to be able to use those internal modules.

Comment: Why you need to define a module inside a module ? You can separate those right ? I think `requirejs` was not meant to do that way

Comment: The library is quite large and splitting it into modules means it's easier to handle.

Comment: You can do that in a different way. Check my answer :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We ended up changing the project to use es6 modules, bable and browserify. This makes everything synchronous instead of being async.

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest your module definitions. Try this instead:

```
define("b", ['somedep','anotherdep'], function(dep, dep2){
    return { something: "x"};
});

define("a", ['b'], function(b){
    return {
        b: b.something
    };
});

// then to use it.
require(['a'], function(a){
});
```

Comment: I don't want to have to expose every module to the outer scope. In this case, module b would contain methods that on their own don't make any sense and that i might want to internally alter without worrying that people will use them

Answer (score 0):

```
// Defined module "b"
define("b", ['somedep','anotherdep'], function(dep, dep2){
    return { something: "x"};
});

// Defined module "a"
define("a", ["b"], function(b){

    return {
        b: b.something
    };
});



// then to use it.
require(['a'], function(a){
});
```

You can do something like this

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to expose the internal define calls externally (by flattening out all the defines) since i don't want library consumers to be able to use those internal modules.

I don't know of a simple way to declare to RequireJS a module and at the same time prevent the module from being able to be used by any code that can call RequireJS's `require`. Let's suppose the code you show would work. Then module `b` would be accessible to any code as soon as module `a` has been loaded. ("Loaded" here means that the factory function has executed.) So while accessing `b` would be dependent on loading `a` first, `b` would not be hidden.

The reason your code does not work is that the "synchronous" `require` of RequireJS is pseudo-synchronous... or perhaps a better term is that it is a pseudo-`require` which *does* operate synchronously but will bail right away if the module you want is not loaded. Again, "loaded" here means **not only** that a `define` call for the module has been executed but that the module's own dependencies are **already loaded** and that the module's factory function **has executed already**. In your code, the dependencies of module `b` have not been loaded and the factory function for `b` has not executed yet, so your `require` call fails.

You'd be able to load `b` with `require(['b'])` but then you'd have to return a promise of some sort from `a`.

You could essentially hide what is in module `b` by using scoping but not making `b` a module:

```
define("a", ['somedep', 'anotherdep'], function(dep, dep2){
    var b = (function (foo, bar) {
        return { something: "x" };
    })(dep, dep2);

    return {
        b: b.something
    };
});
```